# Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1 android studio windows 11

Tags: flutter

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\Users*\AndroidStudioProjects\tutorial_app\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users*.gradle\caches\7.5\scripts\3d075fs9hjp81ny0sgym4v09w).

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 64

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I recently tried running the project (without any modifications) that I had created.